# How do I fix android keyboard cutting off my webview content on dismiss?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-webview, android-keypad

In my current app, whenever I search something in the webview the keyboard pops up as expected. however, when I dismiss the keyboard and reload the page it cuts off the webview content behind the keyboard(shows as blank for the area behind the keyboard).
Is there a way to make it such the even when the keyboard is up the area behind the keyboard is never blank/cut off or a fix for this issue if anyone else had to deal with a similar problem before?

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden" `

Comment: where do i add that? in manifest or the layout

Comment: Yes ,You can put this in your manifest section .

Comment: when I do ,it affects my scrolling capability.I am unable to scroll on the navigation panel

Answer (score 1):

Go to your manifest and add this to your `Activity`

```
<activity
     android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

Comment: that also kills scrolling when keyboard is up

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one

```
 getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(
            android.R.color.transparent);
```

after

```
 setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

Comment: how does the above code affect the inputwindowmanager in any way? i have a function to hidekeyboard before loading the new view upon touch webView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient);
            webView.setOnTouchListenerWebViewClient);
            webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    hideSoftKeyboard();

                  hideSoftKeyboard(View v);
                    return false;
                }
            }); but that doesnt work upon first click